# Atomic update a redis set only if element is not present

Tags: redis

I know barely anything about redis, except it is in-memory and fast.
But I have a case I consider using it.

I have a system, that may have a huge number of users (500k+ may up to a few million) and I want to do a unique check for email adresses across all users. I consider using redis to maintain a set of all email adresses to do the uniquness check. So I asked my self, is it possible to do something like

```
if(!set.contains(email)) add email
```

as an atomic operation and then get a simple result I can handle, just like failure or success.

This code/command should be callable from concurrent code.

If there is a different tool that would fit my needs better, I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`SET`](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) datatype for that:

> Redis Sets are an **unordered collection** of Strings. It is possible to add, remove, and **test for existence** of members in **O(1)** (constant time regardless of the number of elements contained inside the Set).
>
> Redis Sets have the desirable property of not allowing repeated members. Adding the same element multiple times will result in a set having a single copy of this element. **Practically speaking this means that adding a member does not require a check if exists then add operation**.

So just use

```
SADD emails my@email.com
```